# What is the best way to catch keyboard input to Arduino? (not from computer)

Tags: c, performance, keyboard, arduino

I have an Arduino Project where I need some keyboard input. The whole thing is going to run on batteries so having a usb to Computer&computers usb keyboard is not a good choise. I need to attach an external keyboard directly to an Arduino.

PS/2 is NOT an option!

I think there might be some better boards for this but RPi is too heavy and slow(30sec) in the boot.

ty!

Comment: "PS/2 is NOT an option!" Aaaand here comes the pain...

Comment: Just an idea, so I'm not putting as an answer: have you tried seeing what input you get from an ftdi breakout board or chip?

Comment: A PS/2 keyboard may not be an option, but you'll be in over your head if you try to support a USB keyboard without any of the facilities to do so. Best bet would be to find a USB->PS/2 adapter. That, or something like this: http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/usb-host-keyboard